# How to calculate the frequency and duty cycle from excel sheet?

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to ask for opinions and suggestions about finding a square wave frequency and duty cycle. I have an Excel file that contains 4000 samples whose sampling frequency was 4 MHz or 0.25 us time between each sample. In the file 0 represents low and 1 represents HIGH.

I would like to find the frequency of the square wave, using a type of algorithm. My current code works, but not great. I would like to ask other people for their approach and pseudocode to solve this problem. Thanks.

---

Here is how I solve this issue. Maybe it can help someone else too.

```cpp
public double frequencyCalculator(string[] domainChannel)
        {
            int timeHighStart = 0;
            int timeHighEnd = 0;
            int timeLowSideEnd = 0;
            bool highSide = true;
            bool lowSide = false;
            bool processWave = true;
            double samplingPeriod = 0.00025; //each sample is 0.25uS x1000 time should give Khz range 
            int highPulseDuration = 0;
            int lowPulseDuration = 0;
            double periodOfWave = 0;
            double frequencyOfWave = 0;
            decimal dutyCycle = 0;
            int[] domain;
            domain = Array.ConvertAll(domainChannel, int.Parse);


            for (int i = 0; i < domain.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (processWave)
                {
                    if (domain[i] == 0 && domain[i + 1] == 1)
                    {
                        timeHighStart = i;
                    }
                    else if (domain[i] == 1 && domain[i + 1] == 0)//1 to 0 detected 
                    {
                        timeHighEnd = i;
                        highSide = false;
                        lowSide = true;
                    }
                    else if ((lowSide==true) && (domain[i+1] == 0) && (domain[i + 2] == 1))
                    {
                        timeLowSideEnd = i;
                        processWave = false;
                        lowSide = false;
                    }
                }
            }
                    
            highPulseDuration = timeHighEnd - timeHighStart; //  |timeHighStart -timeHighEnd| how many sample is  HIGH part of the pulse
            lowPulseDuration = timeLowSideEnd - timeHighEnd;//  |timeHighEnd-timeLowSideEnd| how many sample is LOW part of the pulse
            periodOfWave = (highPulseDuration + lowPulseDuration)* samplingPeriod; //each time takse 0.25uS to sample 

            frequencyOfWave = 1 / periodOfWave;
            dutyCycle = ((decimal)highPulseDuration / ((decimal)highPulseDuration + (decimal)lowPulseDuration));
            dutyCycle = dutyCycle * 100;

           return frequencyOfWave;

        }
```

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a forum ... please ask a specific, answerable question ... posts requesting opinions are off topic here

Comment: Please show us a sample of your current code. Why do you think that it is not working great. Perhaps it can be salvaged. What programming languages are you familiar with? Python? Matlab? C? C++?

Comment: From Super User.  [How can I record a transition from a 0 to 1 in a column in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/847627/how-can-i-record-a-transition-from-a-0-to-1-in-a-column-in-excel) Second Answer is interesting.  You still have to process the math.

Comment: Please give a sample of what the data looks like

Comment: Baris Metin - Hi, Just to be clear, regarding that code you supplied yesterday (which I moved from an answer, into the question as an update): (a) Is that your *existing* code which you want to improve? (as I originally thought) Or... (b) Is that your *improved* code and so you want to close the question now, because that code solves your problem which you described at the start of your question? Which applies here, (a) or (b)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since your data are already sliced the duty cycle is easy: take the average.

```
=average(a1:a4000)
```

To find frequency, count the number of transitions over the sample buffer interval. SS. Rat linked to a method; I think this is slightly more elegant and accomplishes the same thing (finding positive edges):

```
=SUM((A1:A4000<A2:A4001)*1) + 1
```

(the +1 gets the initial edge in the count.)

Your total time is 0.25us * 4000, or 1ms. So we have:

- (# of edges) / (total time) = frequency

So the Excel formula to count the edges and compute the frequency boils down to:

```
= (SUM((A1:A4000<A2:A4001)*1) + 1) / (0.25e-6 * 4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an autocorrelation algorithm. Basic idea is:

1. Compute the autocorrelation of your sampled data.
2. Determine the peaks.
3. Measure the distance between the peaks. This is your period.

Here's MathWorks article on the technique -- code is given in MATLAB:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/find-periodicity-using-autocorrelation.html

And here's a very pragmatic explanation and implementation of the idea:

https://www.instructables.com/Reliable-Frequency-Detection-Using-DSP-Techniques/

Another thing you can do beforehand is to run a low-pass filter on your data. If you want to stick to processing 0's and 1's you can use a majority filter on your data. Pick an odd number n and replace the sample X[t] with whatever value occurs most often in the n values X[t], X[t-1], X[t-2], ... X[t-n-1].

Comment: The data is already sliced. No need for that.

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: In the OP's question, "In the file 0 represents low and 1 represents HIGH."

Comment: Sure - I understood that. What are you saying there's no need for?

Comment: Autocorrelation. It's overkill for what's being asked.